# Matlab size of image

Tags: matlab

I am trying to find the size of an image I have loaded into matlab.

```
image=imread('text.jpg');
[x,y]=size(image);
```

This return the error:

> Indexing cannot yield multiple results.

Does imread not read the image into a 2d array, which should therefore have two sizes?

Comment: Your code looks OK to me.  Have you tried using, say, imfinfo to see what's in the file ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Is it possible that you have defined a variable named `size` before this code?

Comment: Yes, that was it! Sorry for not spotting the obvious mistake! Thanks.

Answer (score 18):

For those looking to find the size of an image in matlab, don't use:

```
[height, width] = size(image);
```

This is because imread stores the RGB values separately (for colour images), resulting in a three dimensional matrix.

For example, if you loaded a 500p high, 200p wide colour image, this would result in a 500x200x3 matrix.

Calling size() in this way would result in the dimensionality being 'rolled up', and would report the height to be 500, but the width to be 600 (200 * 3).

**Instead, using:**

```
[height, width, dim] = size(image);
```

would return correct values of 500, 200, 3.

Comment: how would i find it out without the RGB values ? i only need the pixels and not the colour.

Answer (score 3):

You must use `[height, width, colour_planes] = size(image);` because images have 3 dimensions. The third dimension is the number of colour planes. If you don't need this value, you can substitute `~` to ignore it.

Comment: what is the 3rd dimension?

Comment: The colour. The 1st dimension is the red values, 2nd is greens, and 3rd is blues

Answer (score 1):

Just use this  `whos` and press enter.

```
image=imread('text.jpg');
whos
```

Answer (score 1):

[x,y,z]=size(image);
is the correct one. x and y will give length and breadth of the image and z specifies color.

Digital image consists of RGB so z will be 3.

Answer (score -3):

You can try this:

```
image=imread('text.jpg');
[x y]=size(image);
```